# Can't link/include GMP when installing Crypt::PBC on Cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin, cpan

I have been trying to install [Crypt::PBC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aPBC) for a couple of weeks but failing to do so. I used `cpan install Crypt::PBC` first and this was the result:

```
Going to read '/home/Mounica/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 23 Apr 2014 23:06:17 GMT
Running install for module 'Crypt::PBC'
Running make for J/JE/JETTERO/Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/www.cpan.org/authors/id/J/JE/JETTERO/Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz
Checksum for /home/Mounica/.cpan/sources/authors/id/J/JE/JETTERO/Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build J/JE/JETTERO/Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz

Use of qw(...) as parentheses is deprecated at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 164.
Error locating libpbc version 0.5.1: Can't link/include 'pbc.h', 'pbc'

You can get the latest debian binaries from https://voltar.org/pbcfiles

Would you like to download and build libpbc from tarball automatically? [y/N] [n]
```

and then when I said yes, I realized that the voltar.org link is broken. This was the message generated:

```
Would you like to download and build libpbc from tarball automatically? [y/N]     [y]
downloading libpbc from http://voltar.org/pbcfiles/pbc-0.5.1.tar.gz...
--2014-04-24 06:33:50--  http://voltar.org/pbcfiles/pbc-0.5.1.tar.gz
Resolving voltar.org (voltar.org)... 69.174.176.168
Connecting to voltar.org (voltar.org)|69.174.176.168|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 File not found
2014-04-24 06:33:51 ERROR 404: File not found.

couldn't fetch with wget...
couldn't fetch with curl ...
unpacking libpbc from pbc-0.5.1.tar.gz...
No files found for pbc-0.5.1.tar.gz at Makefile.PL line 112

gzip: pbc-0.5.1.tar.gz: unexpected end of file
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
failed to unpack pbc
No 'Makefile' created  JETTERO/Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
```

So I unpacked the `Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz` that was downloaded using `tar -xvzf Crypt-PBC-0.9000.tar.gz`. The contents were successfully unpacked. After that, as there was a `Makefile.PL` in it, I used `perl Makefile.pl`. In the makefile I changed the web request to http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/files as a source to pbc files and then used `perl Makefile.pl` again. The following was generated:

```
Use of qw(...) as parentheses is deprecated at inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm line 164.
Error locating libpbc version 0.5.14: Can't link/include 'pbc.h', 'pbc'

You can get the latest debian binaries from http://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/files/

Would you like to download and build libpbc from tarball automatically?[y/N] [y]
(You do need libgmp installed in order for this PBC.so to function...)
Can't link/include 'gmp'
```

I tried including various GMP files in the incpath and libpath but nothing helped. Could you please tell me what are the specific GMP files that are required by this makefile so that i can include those in the INC path?

Comment: Do you use Cygwin as the tag indicates? If yes, please put it in the title to make it clearer.

Comment: I'd advise against using that module: It doesn't make a good impression and hasn't been updated since '09. Anyway, you can get libpbc binaries from the [author](http://jettero.pl/pbcfiles/) or from [stanford](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/download.html). You could try installing the [older v0.855 version](http://search.cpan.org/~jettero/Crypt-PBC-0.855/) or try [forking and fixing the project](https://github.com/jettero/crypt--pbc) or [report a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Crypt-PBC).

Comment: [Alien::GMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Alien::GMP) *might* help installing GMP (that module doesn't seem to function on Cygwin), but you can always dowload GMP from https://gmplib.org/

Comment: @amon I am aware that the link has not been updated and that is why i changed the HTTP request to stanford site.

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I have downloaded and installed GMP from Math::BigInt::GMP and Math::GMP as well